# What happens to our modern society if everyone is shrunk to the size of a Lego minifigure overnight?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, humans

I’m writing a modern-day version of Gulliver’s travels, and I need to understand the impact on our society when everything around us is gigantic, a breeze could feel like a typhoon, a spill becomes a pond, our pet turns nasty, pest remains, death by transportation or by the very smartphone we held in our hand. Everyone is shrunk down to the size of a typical Lego minifigure overnight; the catch is our mass is also scaled proportionately. I think our physiology would not be able to work at such level and this spells the end of humanity, however as the saying goes... life finds a way.

**Is there any way our modern society could still function despite being shrunk or is human becoming extinct?**

Comment: Do they know its going to happen?

Comment: @TrEs-2b: no, its all happened too abruptly.

Comment: You say "I think our physiology would not be able to work at such level"... Should we assume that it magically works, and describe everything else, or also talk about that, but it could be that due to this it isn't necessary to talk about anything else...

Comment: Love the R in the title!

Comment: No time to try to compose a proper answer, but a quick outline of what I would include: 1) The Square-Cube Law means that we become much more robust, but if you really meant it when you stated "mass is also scaled proportionally", then a 70-inch tall 150lb guy becomes a 3lb 1.5-inch tall figure, which is probably not very conformable as his density is probably now above that of depleted uranium. 2) The amount of energy used to regulate body temperature will be similar to that of other small mammals, so we need much more energy relative to normal. 3) Do our brains even work at that size?

Comment: I would regret having two cats that morning.

Comment: Rick Moranis needs to be in it… he hooks his device up to the Internet this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I expect the vast majority of humans would die in short order.  The primary reason is size and distance.  It would be a sufari adventure just for me and my wife to get out of bed and find our way to the floor without getting hurt.  (though with our mass changed we will be able to fall from greater heights and not get hurt much.  It could take us an hour just to get to the kitchen from our bed room, maybe quite a bit longer since we have two steps between the bed room and the kitchen.  I live out in the country and it could take 1-2 days just to reach a neighbors house.

Even in suburbs it could take quite some time to find your neighbors, even if you got to their house.  Are they home?  Did they go looking for someone else?  How well sealed up is your house?  is there any way to get out?

The places with the best chance of humans surviving are where they are pretty dense in population to begin with.  Though you also have pets that will start to get hungry and be looking for a snack.  If they are indoors there is no way for humans to let them out, so they would have to be abandoned before they decided to eat you.

Food will be the single biggest issue, while the first few weeks it will be 'fairly' easy to find and eat food that was out, it gets much harder after that.  Our diet will have to change dramatically.  We'll be hunting bugs and mice and savaging what ever we can find.

So unless enough people can find each other AND find a way to feed and protect one another before they all die out humanity might be doomed.  We'd certainly at the very least be pushed back into the stone age for technology, with interesting pieces of 'tech' available to us.  Pins and needles could be scavenged for decent weapons. etc.

Comment: Actually, if humans scale down. I have a hunch that they would be able to do otherwise impossible feats. So jumping to get to the top of your couch or falling from high heights(at least it's high from the mini Guy's side, in reality it's just a meter) might not be as hard as you think. They would be able to lift many times their body weight and jump many times their height so I think that society could still function. Until the Cats start looking for Lego sized snacks...

Comment: `We'll be hunting bugs and mice and savaging what ever we can find.` Hmmm. "Scavenging", mebbe?

Answer (score 2):

Human will become extinct, and the reason is that if we shrunk to this size, we will become prey for a variety of predators (like mouses, ants, and basically everything bigger than us) and we are not able (nor accustomed) to defend ourselves in such situations, since everyone of our instruments it will be useless and unusable for us.

Another possibility is that in some areas, where people are less dependent from technology, humans survive, but I don't think we will be the dominant species anymore on earth.

Comment: More than anything else I've read, your answer has made me wonder if it's possible to hotwire a RC Car... from inside.

Comment: @ScottDowney: probably not. They are not designed with this in mind...

Comment: @ScottDowney they do make RC ones, and you could probably edit the controls to be from the inside.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the population dies of thirst/starvation.
Anyone in a room with closed doors is stuck - the door handle is now the equivalent of hundreds of feet up.

If the door is open, you have simiilar problems getting water - how do you get up to the taps? can you turn the tap when you get there? how do you get to where the water is once it's running, and back out afterwards?
How do you open cans of food? you'd need a gang to move a tin opener.

Distribution of goods collapses.

Anything that needs operator intervention probably fails rapidly.

Only those who can get outside somewhere where they can live off the land have a chance.

Comment: Who says you need to open the door. Just go under.